# Pasar de formato telefono a un number en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia, es posible en javascript pasar este telefono +1 (833) 555-2739 a formato numero? si tengo +1 (833) 555-2739 que me devuelva 18335552739

Comment: ¡Bienvenido, TrasharTheDragon! Sería recomendable que primero intentes solucionar tu pregunta y así podremos ayudarte con lo que tengas.

Comment: Realmente eso di a entender, no entiendo como cambiar la pregunta

Comment: puedes usando expresiones regulares, quitar los caracteres que no quieras

Comment: @TrasharTheDragon deberías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que has intentado. La respuesta a tu pregunta actual es: si

Comment: No he hecho codigo, preferi primero preguntar antes de hacer codigo

Comment: Ya te dieron una pista, intenta resolverlo y si no te sale volve y actualiza tu pregunta.

Comment: Con todo respeto es molesto que uno siendo claro aun asi no entiendan mi pregunta, solo lo primero es irse si la pregunta esta bien, ya fui claro pero no entiendo porque no entiende y al final nadie ayuda

Comment: No es que no se entienda tu pregunta, es que nosotros esperamos que primero hayas intentado resolverlo por tu cuenta y luego preguntado. Recuerda que aqui [no hacemos tareas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874). Si vas a preguntar aqui, te recomiendo primero intentar y luego preguntar demostrando tus intentos/investigación.

Comment: Lo hice pero realmente no llegué a nada, preferi descartar lo que hice y pedir una opinión que tenga mas lógica que la que tengo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con expresiones regulares, por ejemplo

```
function telToNumber(str) {
const regex = /[0-9]/gm
let m;
let result = []

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach(match => {
        result.push(match)
    });
}

return result.join('')
}
telToNumber('+1 (833) 555-2739') //retornara "18335552739"
```

espero que te haya ayudado

Comment: gracias era lo que necesitaba, me molesta que intento ser lo mas claro y muchos no ayudan y solo porque segun la pregunta no la entienden, es estresante